# HTML output with spaces in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've never met this behaviour while working with laravel, but now I got something annoying. I have this code:

```
     <span class="category-list">
            (@foreach ($material->categories as $category)
                {{ $category->name }}
            @endforeach) )
     </span>
```

And I got this output:

[image]

As you can see I got a lot of spaces here. I suppose that's because I have tabs in my code (tabs automatically converted to spaces in phpstorm). But how to deal with it except having ugly code without spaces?

I think I'm missing something simple as I've never had such trouble

Answer (score 1):

Where is this data coming from? What happens when you dump this from your controller? (still extra whitespace?)

If the whitespace is indeed in the property itself and it serves a purpose, you could make a `Macro` to `trim()` it, or `trim()` it in-line.

**trim():**

```
 <span class="category-list">
        (@foreach ($material->categories as $category)
            {{ trim($category->name) }}
        @endforeach) )
 </span>
```

**Or Macro:**

**Macro:** (register the macro)

```
Form::macro('trimWhitespace', function($val)
{
    // do anything you want to $val.

    return trim($val);
});
```

**View:** (use the macro)

```
 <span class="category-list">
        (@foreach ($material->categories as $category)
            {{ Form::trimWhitespace($category->name) }}
        @endforeach) )
 </span>
```

Comment: `Form::macro`? Wouldn't `Str::macro` is the more appropriate choice here?

Comment: Good call.  I didn't even know that method existed.